# Creating a matrix for R

Tags: type-conversion

I have a txt file with two columns.

```
A= gene names
B= tumors with mutation in that gene
```

I want to produce a file that is a matrix with all tumors listed in one column and then all the gene names across in a row.  See attachment for example

Can this be done with R or awk?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0VXe.png)

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Please show your existing code - see [ask] and [mcve]. Remember that SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I'm very new to coding so I don't currently have a code to achieve this

Comment: OK. Use `read.table` and then `tidyr::gather` or base R `reshape`. Good luck.